# MySQL index to get record between 2 columns used for range

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a MySQL table for cities ip blocks,

```
ip_ranges(city_id, CIDR, start_ip_decimal, end_ip_decimal)
```

Data types are as follows

1. city_id `[unsigned bigint]`
2. CIDR `[varchar 255]`
3. start_ip_decimal `[unsigned bigint]` : Start ip range is converted into decimal
4. end_ip_decimal `[unsigned bigint]`: End ip range is converted into decimal

So what I am doing is,to convert the user ip to decimal, and check in this table to get the `city_id`. but the query take too much time **70 seconds** to lookup a city_id

```
SELECT city_id FROM ip_ranges WHERE 658206441 BETWEEN start_ip_decimal and end_ip_decimal
```

or

```
SELECT city_id FROM ip_ranges WHERE start_ip_decimal <= 658206441 AND end_ip_decimal >= 658206441
```

**Note:** 658206441 is decimal value converted from user's ip address

**InnoDB** is used as a database engine.
There are total **10664916** records in this table.

> Corei7 2.0GHz and 2.6 GHz Processor with 8 GB Ram (windows 10)

So my question is how can I speed up this lookup.

I tried with applying index on start and end field 
Index type `Normal` and Index method `BTREE`, but it has no impact.

Here is how DDL look like

```
CREATE TABLE `ip_ranges` (
  `cidr` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_ip_decimal` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_ip_decimal` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `city_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `my_index` (`start_ip_decimal`,`end_ip_decimal`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Solution:** I have solved (I think so) my problem based on @RickJames comments, but I might have missed few parts of his response.

First thing learnt is

> Range tests like IP-addresses are difficult. No simple index works
>   well.

So I performed following steps to achieve what I wanted.

**1** Ignored the `end` field, After Jame's comment I realized, in every row `start` fields is equal to `end+1` of the previous row.

> However, if, instead of a range, you have just a starting IP, and have
>   the 'end' being the start of the next row, it can be made much more
>   efficient.

```
network     start       end
--------------------------------
1.0.0.0/24  16777216    16777471
1.0.1.0/24  16777472    16777727
1.0.2.0/23  16777728    16778239
```

However there might be some issues for missed ranges

**2** Applied `UNIQUE` key `index` on `start` column using `BTREE`

**3** Modified `SELECT` query as follows

```
SELECT * FROM ip_ranges
WHERE $ipNumberToCheck >= `start` ORDER BY `start` DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: What you mean under `Note: 658206441 is decimal value converted from user's ip address` ? can you add example to what converted e.g. `45.80.135.18` ip address ? to `458013518` ? or ?

Comment: When you created the index, did you include both columns in a single index, or did you create two separate indexes?

Comment: Single index with 2 fields
KEY `my_index` (`start_ip_decimal `,`end_ip_decimal `) USING BTREE

Comment: @Armen please have a look on this link it converts ip to decimal value
http://www.ipaddressguide.com/ip

Comment: `INT UNSIGNED` is big enough for IPv4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it is `INT UNSIGNED` (not signed).

I presume you are not worrying about IPv6?

Range tests like IP-addresses are difficult.  No simple index works well.  The KEY you have will scan, on average, 5 million rows.

However, if, instead of a range, you have just a starting IP, and have the 'end' being the start of the next row, it can be made much more efficient.  This also involves `ORDER BY ip LIMIT 1`.  And it involves having entries for the unused IP ranges.  I cover all of this, plus efficient code, in [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ipranges).  It includes stored routines for IPv4 (like you are using) and IPv6.  It will find the city in a single row fetch, regardless of the table size.  So it is limited to one disk hit (roughly speaking).  Logically, it is 5 million times as fast; but in reality the 70 seconds should drop to a few milliseconds.

Comment: Please have a look on my solution, if I may have missed some thing?

Comment: `ORDER BY LIMIT 1` is the trick.  Two more things I do in my blog:  Get rid of the 'end' column and fill in any gaps.